# Setting the value of a Html textbox from the Asp.Net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, html, code-behind

I'm trying to set a value from the database into a Html component, the code is as follow:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbFiltroCostesPre" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="286px">
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="A">All</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="Greater">First 10</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="GreaterThan">Greater than: &lt;input ID=&quottxtGreaterThan&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; &gt;</asp:ListItem>                                              
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The last ListItem has a Html tag inside, like:

```
<input id="txtGreaterThan" type="text"/>
```

, which has been transform by the Visual Web Development IDE.

Can I set it's value dynamically from the codebehind? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't do that with the managed [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) control.  What's happening in your page is it's setting the `Text` value of your ListItem with `Greater than: &lt;input ID=&quottxtGreaterThan&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; &gt;`.

What you could do is to use a [RadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx) instead of a `RadioButtonList` and place a `TextBox` control next to the RadioButton. This would allow you to access it server-side.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. If I look the source code from the web page, the generated code, for the last item is:  <label for="rbFiltroCostesPre_2">
Coste mayores que:
<input id="txtCostesMayoresQue" class="numeric" type="text" name="txtCosteMayorQue" runat="server" style="width: 57px">
%
</label>  So you can see I still have an input with Id. Thx

Comment: That's because you're "faking it out" by placing HTML inside your text of the ListItem. So it will render the HTML, but it will not be a managed control. I've updated my answer with a suggestion on using a managed control.

Comment: Yes¡ the use of radioButton instead of radioButtonList does the trick. THKX. I would vote you, but I can't. Thanks again